# Missing space when replacing with \regex_replace_all:nnN

Tags: latex3, l3regex

How can I make `\regex_replace_all:nnN` not remove the space between `x y`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \replace #1#2#3
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl  {#3}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\replace{a}{x y}{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Spaces are ignored in the first two arguments of `\regex_replace_all:nnN`; you should use `\cS\ ` for a space

Comment: That works. Thanks. But what would be a more systematic way of doing that?

Comment: I guess this is the best method. Making (unescaped) spaces not being ignored would pose very big problems. And you have to take into account that characters in TeX have also a category code.

Comment: I see. The problem is asking users who only know the interface to do that. :)

Comment: If the replacement is that simple, you can also use `\tl_replace_all:Nnn`

Comment: Remember that the regex code is meant for 'code level' manipulation: using regexes within a document body is not really the usual LaTeX way! If you really want to allow spaces in the regexes, I guess you could first use a pre-defined regex to replace any spaces in them with escaped ones, then use the result as the 'real' regex for the replacement.

Comment: Actually now `\ ` gives spaces with the standard category code (i.e. no need for `\cS\ `).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax rules for regex substitutions are rather bizarre under some respects; as the documentation specifies, significant spaces in the search or the replacement strings should always be escaped, because unescaped spaces are ignored.

Moreover you need to specify that you want a "real" space with the right category code; if you simply say `x\ y` in the replacement string, you'd get a category code 12 space, which would print whatever character is in slot 32 of the current font (which in OT1 encoding is a strange glyph and in T1 encoding, but also in T2A, is a "visible space").

So the most correct syntax would be

```
\replace{a}{\cLx\cS\ \cLy}{abc}
```

where you specify that you want x and y as normal letters: by default `l3regex` uses category code 12 characters. However this is being picky, as category code 12 and 11 characters are indistinguishable when printed.

For simple substitutions like that you could use

```
\tl_replace:Nnn
```

So, for example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\replace}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#3}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {#1} {#2}
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\replace{a}{x y}{abc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Is there any way that could also work for `\replace{a}{x y}{\textbf{a}bc}`?

Comment: @nicolai.rostov Sorry, not without regex.

Comment: @egreg: What is the last `\l_tmpa_la` in the line `\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl` for? As far as I can see it’s no argument of `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` …

Comment: @Tobi It's a misprint, probably a remains of a previous version of the code. Thanks for noting

Comment: @egreg: Thanks and merry Christmas :-)